# issue with tabindex in c# .net

Tags: c#

If you will look at this image:

[image: .net c# dialog]

The blue numbers represent the tab index property that I have for the controls. My problem is that when I put the focus on the first textbox control and start hitting TAB it goes from index 0 to 1 to 5 and skips the three controls that are in the group box.

How can I set this up so that when I put the focus on the first text box (index 0) and continue to TAB it will cycle straight from controls 0 to 5 without skipping over the controls in the group box?

Comment: Don't .NET controls have a property called Z-Order that affects the order of TAB-selection?

Comment: ^There is no z-order property that is accessible. There IS a BringToFront method but that does not do me much good in this scenario.

Comment: ^^(Oded) Sorry about that I will correct the problem when I get home later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio open your windows forms designer. Go to menu 'View' and then use 'Tab Order'.
Here you will see the tree-like control order.
Just click the controls in the order you want to have.

Comment: I can already see that. If I could edit the numbers rather than just incriment them I could fix it. It appears that the controls in the group box are nested and are not accessible unless I put the focus on a control that is already in the group box (and that nested group).

Comment: Is the group box a seperate UserControl?

Comment: Yes. It is a System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox. I dragged and dropped the checkbox and textbox controls into it.

Comment: 1) you can try to set the groupboxes tab index (same way as i wrote)  2) you can try to edit (carefully!) the tab index in the ???.dessigner.cs file

Comment: I had not clicked on the groupbox while using the taborder tool. Stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I found that, in addition to setting the tab order/tab index, I needed to be certain that TabStop = true. This issue (false) was causing my group of controls to be skipped.